# How to properly override HttpURLConnection connect() method in Java

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection

I have a class that extends `java.net.HttpURLConnection`. I am developing for Android and dealing with digest auth (which is not natively supported via URLConnection).

Originally I wanted to override the `connect()` method so that I could call `super.connect()` look at the response code and then perform the digest auth "under the hood" if we get a 401. The connect method is declared as abstract in the original java.net class so it must be implemented. I wanted to find source for this method (since you can call it when dealing with a standard instance) but couldn't find anything to show me what's going on underneath.

My next choice was to override `getResponseCode` but again I must provide a body for `connect()`.

So does anyone know what `HttpURLConnection.connect()` actually does? and am I going about this correctly?

Answer (score 0):

For a source of inspiration in writing your own code, go look into the openjdk code.
grepcode.com for example, and [here's some (old) underwear to handle https connections](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/com/sun/net/ssl/internal/www/protocol/https/).
Feel free to explore around in other packages as well, you may find [newer stuff](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/javax/net/ssl/HttpsURLConnection.java?av=f)

Answer (score 0):

Take a Look in my example to connect using HttpUrlConnection and return a JSON String.
See in: https://gist.github.com/marlusantos/1004ee13e528b2e99dd528ceb2294d1b
This case I used in an AsyncTask.

Answer (score 0):

So according to my research it is actually       `sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection` that is returned as a concrete object/type when calling `URL.openConnection()` with HTTP protocol. This is the concrete class I should be deriving from to make life easier rather than having to implement the abstract class `java.net.HttpURLConnection`.

This way I can override the `connect()` method to support digest auth etc.